# grub recovery mode: etc/resolv.conf: no such file or directory

Tags: ubuntu, networking, networkmanager, resolv.conf

I’ve installed Ubuntu 16.04 on my laptop a few months ago and suddenly I can t get past the splash screen.

[image: Where I’m stuck]

(I see the red dots gradually becoming white and vice-versa, so something is happening, but I can t get past this screen)

I thus decided to boot in recovery mode to update and upgrade all my packages. But once I get there I have no internet access (with or without Ethernet cable). This is what I get when trying to enable networking:

[image]

Could someone explain me how to have internet access so I can hopefully be able to solve my other issue in order to be able to log in again on my machine?

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it

Comment: Do this echo "nameserver 8.8.8.8" | sudo tee /etc/resolv.conf Then try connecting to Internet.

Answer (score 1):

On the menu, enable networking.

Next, drop into a root-shell. Verify with `ifconfig -a` that your network is available.If it is not, give your device a fixed IP address in such a way that it can communicate with your gateway.

Verify with `netstat -rn` that your default gateway is correct. If not, configure it with `route add default gw xx.xx.xx.xx`.

You should now be able to ping 8.8.8.8.

Verify that your root filesystem is not mounted read only with mount. If it is, remount it RW.

Put `nameserver 8.8.8.8` in /etc/resolv.conf. Verify with `ping google.com` that name resolution works.